# Secure nodejs app with OAuth2, not automatically redirected to allow / deny page

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, sails.js, passport.js, oauth2orize

I've set up a project to secure a sails application with OAuth2: https://github.com/lucj/sails-oauth2-api

I have a problem with the Authorization Code Grant that I do not manage to solve.

Basically, This are the steps I follow:
- run the sails app
- run the unTrustedClient (node untrustedClient.js within the example folder)
- from a web browser, I then issue the following URL:

```
http://localhost:1337/oauth/authorize?client_id=O3UTGRFNI1&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:1339&scope=http://localhost:1337
```

Note: the value of the client_id is the one displayed for untrustedTestClient in the sails terminal when the application starts

This redirect me toward the 'login' page, which is fine.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2330187/login.png

But when I submit the credentials (me@gmail.com /password by default) I'm redirected towards /index and not toward the original URL (the one above).

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2330187/index.png

I need to re-issue the URL above for the dialog page (the one with the Allow / Deny options) to be displayed.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2330187/allow_deny.png

I'm using 'connect-ensure-login' middleware.

```
app.get('/oauth/authorize',
    login.ensureLoggedIn(),
    server.authorize(function(clientId, redirectURI, done) {

      Client.findOne({clientId: clientId}, function(err, client) {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (!client) { return done(null, false); }
        if (client.redirectURI != redirectURI) { return done(null, false); }
        return done(null, client, client.redirectURI);
      });
    }),
    server.errorHandler(),
    function(req, res) {
      res.render('dialog', { transactionID: req.oauth2.transactionID,
                             user: req.user,
                             client: req.oauth2.client
      });
    }
  );
```

How can I fix this so the redirection is done automatically once I enter the credentials ?